# Set specific aspect ratio for narrow matrix - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 13x1340 matrix that I usually plot correctly without the need to specify an aspect ratio.

However, I would now like to tweak that aspect ratio so that two matrices whose 13 rows correspond to different scales are plotted as rectangles of equal length but different height, proportionally to the corresponding axis scale.

I have tried to use the get_aspect() method to obtain the numerical value that is being used, but it returns 'auto'. I have tried to guess the value and found that it is close to 4.5/(1340*180), which looks like a completely absurd value to me. I expected it to be something closer to 13/1340, but perhaps I don't quite understand how aspect ratios are calculated.

Setting the aspect ratio to 1 gives me an incredibly thin figure, with the proper vertical size. As the value decreases, the figure becomes longer in length, until it reaches ~ 4.5/(1340*180). After that, it starts losing height while keeping a fixed length.

Figure size is set to 3 inches high by 7 inches large, and the dpi is set to 300 on the savefig() method.

The get_data_ratio() method returns a value slightly larger than 13*1340, although it is clear that this value is not the aspect ratio used do construct the figure.